# 'Key' object has no attribute 'database' Error in Google Cloud Ndb

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am running an google appengine app using python 3.9. I use cloud ndb as a database for my app.
My app has a customer ndb model. When creating an entity everything works fine. However when I want to update an entity the app throws this error.

Here is my code for adding a new customer

```
newCustomer = customer( number = number,
               addedBy = ndb.Key('employee',int(employeeId)),
               firstName = firstname,
               lastName = lastname,
               phone = phone,
               countryCode= countryCode)
order_key = newCustomer.put()
```

Here is my code for updating

```
customer = ndb.Key('customer',customer_id).get()
customer.firstName = firstName
customer.lastName = lastName
customer.phone = phone
customer.countryCode = countryCode
customer_key = customer.put()
```

Here is the Error I got

```
AttributeError at /customer/edit/6199943289110528
'Key' object has no attribute 'database'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/customer/edit/6199943289110528
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Key' object has no attribute 'database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the version of the `google-cloud-ndb`.
I reinstall the latest version of google-cloud-ndb with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code:

```
client = ndb.Key('customer',customer_id).get()
customer.firstName = firstName
customer.lastName = lastName
customer.phone = phone
customer.countryCode = countryCode
customer_key = customer.put()
```

To something like this:

```
existingCustomer = ndb.Key('customer',customer_id).get()
existingCustomer.firstName = firstName
existingCustomer.lastName = lastName
existingCustomer.phone = phone
existingCustomer.countryCode = countryCode
customer_key = existingCustomer.put()
```

`customer` is the name of your ndb model class and you need to distinguish that from instances/objects that you create with the class.

Also, this is a better way to get the existing customer:

```
existingCustomer = customer.get_by_id(customer_id)
```